# How can I delete the PostgreSQL user in my mac? because, there is no user in the preference

Tags: macos, user-account, postgresql

I forgot how I install postgresql before.
and now I have removed it by following this steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/9240197/12381565 .

But my postgresql user didn't gone from the taskbar,
although in my user preference is doesn't have it, so I can't remove it again in the preference. 
[image: the screenshot]

Maybe I deleted it once, but I forgot about it.

thank you.

Comment: Perhaps it's cached. What happens when you restart your Mac?

Comment: I did it 2 times after follow these steps. but still like this. and btw, there is no options to choose the user in startup, so it's only show in taskbar, and when I clicked it, it will switch the user and need to input the password to log-in, but I tried all my password that I remember, it always wrong password.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution!
here is the link:
[Remove PostgreSQL account from system](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/438507/478184)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).