# Remove PostgreSQL account from system

Tags: macos, postgresql

When I am accessing Fast User Switching, there is a PostgreSQL account:

[image]
I have uninstalled PostgreSQL account a while back, looked out libraries and no trace of folder PostgreSQL.

I am aware that I can hide this account, but it would be ideal to delete it completely.

Comment: Is the account visible in System Preferences > Users & Groups? If it is, you can delete it by selecting it and pressing the minus button.

Comment: Account is not visible in Users & Groups.

Comment: In the Directory Utility app (press Command-Space, type "Directory Utility" and select the app by that name to launch it) under Directory Editor, if you select Viewing Users in node /Local/Default, do you see a PostgreSQL user? If that's the case, you can authenticate by pressing the lock icon and delete it. Before doing so,   write down the value of `UniqueID` and `NFSHomeDirectory`. After deleting the user, you can check if the folder specified by `NFSHomeDirectory` contains files you want to keep. If it doesn't, you can delete it.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. If you could please add your comment as an answer, I can mark it as a correct solution.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help, I've consolidated both comments into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first place to look for accounts is System Preferences > Users & Groups. If the account is listed there, you can delete it by selecting it and pressing the minus button (you may need to press the lock button to enable changes):

[image]

If the account is not listed in System Preferences > Users & Groups, you can use the Directory Utility app:

1. Press Command-Space, type "Directory Utility" and select the app by that name to launch it:
   [image]
2. Open the Directory Editor tab and select "Viewing Users in node `/Local/Default`":
   [image]
3. Authenticate by pressing the lock icon.
   [image]
4. Scroll down the list until you find the account you want to delete and select it.
5. For reference, write down the value of `NFSHomeDirectory` and `UniqueID` (`NFSHomeDirectory` is the user's [home directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory), it may contain files you want to keep. `UniqueID` is the [User ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier) that unambiguously identifies files owned by the user - you can find those files with this command: `find / -uid <UniqueID> 2>/dev/null`.)
6. Press the minus button to delete the account.
7. Quit Directory Utility.